# Jordan decomposition in Takesaki: theorem III.2.2.1

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Consider the following fragment from Takesaki's book "Theory of operator algebras I":

[image]

Takesaki says that by passing to the unitisation, it suffices to show the proposition for unital $C^*$-algebras. I don't see why this is the case. I understand the proof of the unital case so this can be freely used. I tried the following:

Let $A$ be non-unital. If $\omega$ is a hermitian functional on $A$, then we can define
$$\widetilde{\omega}: \widetilde{A}\to \mathbb{C}: a + \lambda 1 \mapsto \omega(a) + \lambda$$
which is again hermitian (but is it also bounded??).

Then we can apply the unital result and write
$$\widetilde{\omega}= \widetilde{\omega}_+ - \widetilde{\omega}_-, \|\widetilde{\omega}\| = \|\widetilde{\omega}_+\| + \|\widetilde{\omega}_-\|.$$
Defining $\omega_+ = \widetilde{\omega}_+\vert_A$ and $\omega_- = \widetilde{\omega}_-\vert_A$, we get $\omega = \omega_+-\omega_-$ as a difference of two positive linear functionals on $A$. However, it is not clear to me why
$$\|\omega_+\| + \|\omega_-\| = \|\omega\|$$
in this case!

I think if the following result is true, then I can finish the proof:

If $\omega \in S(\widetilde{A})$ is a state and $\omega\vert_A \ne 0$, then $\omega\vert_A$ is also a state. But I don't know why this should be true. Any help/comment/remark is highly appreciated!

Comment: All the statements you use or remark about are true. Better than just true: They are "elementary" after you have worked through a basic treatment of the space of states of a $C^*$ algebra. I can recommend the book by Murphy or by Brattelli and Robinson (I haven't read Takesaki, but it might be too advanced as a complete introduction)

Comment: @s.harp Thanks for your comment. Can you then tell me why the restriction of a state $\omega \in S(\widetilde{A})$ to the subalgebra $A$ is again a state? I checked Murphy but couldn't find anything.

Comment: You are right, sorry, that part is only almost true. Any state on $A$ admits a unique extension to a state on $\widetilde A$, but the other direction doesn't go because there is a kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with a selfadjoint $\omega$ on $A$. Extend by Hahn-Banach to a functional $\omega'$ on $\tilde A$ with $\|\omega'\|=\|\omega\|$. Define
$$
\tilde\omega(x)=\tfrac12\,\big(\omega'(x)+\overline{\omega'(x^*)}\big).
$$
Then $\tilde\omega$ is selfadjoint. We have $\|\tilde\omega\|\leq\|\omega'\|=\|\omega\|$, but as it extends $\omega$, we get $\|\tilde\omega\|=\|\omega\|$. So we end up with a selfadjoint extension of $\omega$ to $\tilde A$, that preserves the norm.

The argument in Takesaki's book gives you
$$
\frac\omega{\|\omega\|}=\lambda\omega_1-\mu\omega_2.
$$
These are states in the unitization. But they are also states in $A$. In principle you know that $\|\omega_j\|\leq1$, $j=1,2$. But since the left-hand-side has norm 1, you have
$$
1=\|\lambda\omega_1-\mu\omega_2\|\leq\lambda\|\omega_1\|+\mu\|\omega_2\|\leq\lambda+\mu=1. 
$$
The only way for this to be an equality is if $\|\omega_1\|=\|\omega_2\|=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why is the left hand side a state on $A$? I.e. why is $\|\frac{\omega\vert_A}{\|\omega\|}\| = 1$? This is equivalent with $\|\omega\| = \|\omega\vert_A\|.$

Comment: The proof is about a selfadjoint linear functional $\omega$ on $A$. Then $\omega/\|\omega\|$ is a state. In the proof, you work in unitization (i.e., you use the extension of $\omega$ to $\tilde A$) to obtain $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$.

Comment: But $\omega$ is self-adjoint? If $\omega/\|\omega\|$ is a state, then $\omega$ is necessarily positive and I don't think this is true.

Comment: You are right, but the only problem is the word "state". All the argument uses is that $\omega/\|\omega\|$ has norm 1.

Comment: Do we need to show that a hermitian functional $\omega$ on $A$ extends to a hermitian functional with the same norm on the unitisation $\widetilde{A}$?

Comment: Indeed. I included a paragraph at the beginning to address that.

Comment: Splendid! All clear now. I learn a lot from your answers!

Comment: Nice to hear :)